# Delete record from console in Hanami

Tags: ruby, hanami

In Rails you can do:

```
rails c
record = Record.where(name: 'Test Record').first
record.destroy
```

How can you do the same in Hanami? I've been reading through the docs but I'm struggling to see how to do console commands like Rails to interact with the database objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
$ hanami c
UserRepository.new.users.where(name: "Test Record").delete
```

Answer (score 1):

When a class inherits from `Hanami::Repository`

`delete(id)` – Delete the record corresponding to the given id

in Hanami use `delete` instead of `destroy`

Comment: But how do I get to the record via console?

Comment: you install  `hanami-cli` if not install yet  `  $ gem install hanami-cli  `

Comment: `hanami-cli` is a gem to build CLI apps with Ruby. If you use Hanami you don't need to install it, but to use the CLI that ships with the gem: `hanami`.